# Add modified copy of a row into Data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, indexing, append

Let's say we have a data frame below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(numpy.random.randint(0,5,size=(5, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df
   A  B  C  D
0  3  3  0  0
1  0  3  3  2
2  1  0  0  0
3  2  4  4  0
4  3  2  2  4
```

I would want to append a new row from the existing data and modify several columns

```
newrow = df.loc[0].copy()
newrow.A = 99
newrow.B = 90
df.append(newrow)
```

By doing this I got a warning when trying to modify the row

```
See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
<string>:23: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

1. What would be the clean way of achieving what I intend to do ? I won't have index to use loc because the row is not inside the df yet
2. If later I would like to come back to this row, how could I retrieve its index at the moment of appending.

> ```
> newrow = df.loc[0].copy()
> df.append(newrow)
> df.loc[which index to use, "A"] = 99
> ```

In other words, let's say I would want to add the row first then modify it later, how could I get the added row's index

Answer (score 2):

As I can see, you modify every value of the current df row, so it might unnecessary to copy the current row and get the warning.

Just create a `dict` with your values and append it to the `df`:

```
newrow = {'A':99,'B':90,'C':92, 'D':93}
df = df.append(newrow, ignore_index=True)
```

Use `ignore_index=True` and the `newrow` will just be the last index in your df.

Comment: Some more precision : I would prefer not to create from scratch. That's why  I copied. Imagine 30 columns and I'd need to modify 2 or 3 columns.

Comment: Thanks for the revision. Actually I've just run the exact code you provided and the SettingWithCopyWarning error didn't show up. I'm using Pandas 0.21.0 and Python 3.5.2.

Comment: I agree, I cannot seem to reproduce the error with this example. The process chain was reading from a serialized data frame, make a copy of 1 row and modify it. I am not sure which part of the chain raise this issue. We'll raise it again if we find out the real scenario where the warning appears. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use `df.iloc[-1]` to find the appended line if you didn't use the `ignore_index = True` tip.